# How to run .NET Framework 4.0 website on IIS6 with existing framework 2.0 websites

Tags: .net, asp.net, frameworks, iis-6

Please tell me how to run .net framework 4.0 web sites on IIS6. we already have existing website on same server running on .net framework 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Create a separate application pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757073%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for your 4.0 applications and make that run 4.0 or even better have an application pool per application so you isolate them.

If you're upgrading you might want to have a look at [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/05/30/ASPNet_5F00_regiis.exe-tool_2C00_-setting-the-default-version-without-forcing-an-upgrade-on-all-sites.aspx) on how to set the framework version from command line.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the website you want to run with .NET 4.0, switch to the tab "ASP.NET" and select `4.0.<build-version-depending-on-your-patch-level>` from the "ASP.NET version" dropdown list.

If Framework 4.0 is not shown you need to run **aspnet_regiis.exe** from the 4.0 Framework directory to register .NET Framework 4.0 with IIS.